# Variables for multiples pages html for one external script javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to know if this is possible to take the value of one input (HTML) from one page to the second page and print it with one external script (JavaScript)

HTML1:

```
<label id="text">Paris </label><button onclick="onClick()">Send</button>
```

HTML2:

```
<label id="city"></label>
```

I want to know how I can print 'Paris', that is both in Html1 and HTML2, with one external script when I click send

Comment: How are the pages connected? Was one opened by a `window.open` from the other?

Comment: the two pages connected with one script(javascscript) i used window.open() to move to the second page but i did'nt find how to get the variable of html1 to html2???

Comment: If they're on the same domain, you can manipulate the opened window via the opener. `const w = window.open(...); w.document.querySelector('#city').textContent = 'foo';`

Comment: it's not working after i open the second page i can't modifie the page, i can't access to the "label city"

Comment: Taking your question at face value and without considering it an XY problem, it sounds like you want the functionality that [Shared Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker)s provide.  However, I think you should describe what **exactly** you are trying to do so that we can suggest the appropriate path forward as SharedWorkers may be overkill for your task.